# Formatting hard disk

Tags: xubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.4 LTS in my desktop. I want to remove it and install Xubuntu. Can anyone tell how to remove Ubuntu from my hard disk instead of using the option to erase disk while installing Xubuntu? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why won't that method work?

Comment: Its actually not giving me that option while I try to install it

Comment: Ah. Well, if you choose to try Ubuntu instead of Install, you can open Gparted and use that to format the drive.

Comment: It is not booting up from the flash drive. I dunno why. Which is why I thought it better to clean the hard disk and then install Xubuntu externally

Comment: If the reason for installing Xubuntu is to use its desktop environment, well you can install that using `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`. But if you still want to remove the existing OS, anytime you can just format it. What options do you get? You must get option for formatting disk in installation

Comment: @SanketGupte if it won't boot into the installation, how are you going to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: If you cannot boot, ask question about booting from USB. How have you made bootable USB?

Comment: No I am not getting it @Mostafa Ahangarha. Which is why I am opting to format it. Second thing is Ubuntu 10.4 has reached EOL which is why I wanna change it.

Comment: I made my usb bootable by using universal usb installer. When I disconnect the hard disk and boot from usb it boots ok but when I connect my hard disk it does not boot from usb.

Comment: It seems the priority of boot is for HDD. Make sure it is set to USB

Comment: I did it @MostafaAhangarha

Comment: This problem occurs even with setting the USB as first boot option in BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect Harddisk and USB both, at startup BIOS time press F12/F9(Find Boot key according to your manufacturer) and select USB, then at partion selection menu select old Xubuntu Partition and Tick check box mentioning Format(Dont forget to backup your data), and install Ubuntu, hopefully it works, thanks

Comment: I did exactly same thing but even after setting the boot order to boot usb first, it still does not boot from usb. Therefore I don't get the try or install option in grub